# Form Boundary is being written to my file when I upload to server, making it corrupt

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload, axios, postman

I've now tried this with Postman and with a basic form submitted with Axios.

I'm generating signedUrls for S3 so I can put an object in my bucket. It's working, all good, files go into the bucket. However, I noticed my step functions were failing due to errors in the Zip files, and after looking into I noticed that files uploaded via a form are slightly bigger than those uploaded directly to S3 through the admin interface.

I opened the Zip file in a text editor and found a wrapper around the content that looks like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary19fSiKSo1hKo8CkO
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="surveys.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed
```

and then at the bottom

```
------WebKitFormBoundary19fSiKSo1hKo8CkO--
```

When I delete those, I can open the file and see the files. I initially was testing with Postman and thought maybe it was the culprit, but after making a form with Axios, I'm seeing the same thing.

Any idea how to fix this? I've tried adding/removing headers, but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out. Evidently Postman and the way I built my Axios form had the same problem. I was serializing the form instead of just posting the data to the signed url.

Instead of submitting data as `FormData`, I just submitted it directly like this

```
let data = document.getElementById('file').files[0]
axios.put(signedUrl, data)
```